# Call to a member function encodePassword() on null, Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to save an encoded password to my entity by using the UserPasswordEncoderInterface class.

```
class UserFixture extends Fixture
{
private $encoder;

public function _construct( UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder){
    $this->encoder = $encoder;
}

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername('admin');
    $user->setPassword(
        $this->encoder->encodePassword($user, '0000')
    );
    $user->setEmail('no-reply@hotmail.com');
    $manager->persist($user);

    $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the follwing error: `Call to a member function encodePassword() on null`. Can't find what I'm doing wrong here!

Comment: __construct might help.  And are you new'ing UserFixture or injecting it.

Comment: What do you mean by "_construct might help"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first check your namespace, but as @Cerad says, you mistyped `__construct()` which is the reason why your `encoder` is null.

The right command to use in order to load your fixture properly might be :

`php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load`

As the documentation recommends : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't see how i mistyped '_construct()'

Comment: Two under bars, not one.

Comment: In PHP,  the constructor method must be prefixed with two underscores : `_construct` -> `__construct`.